# 'Multi' method is not allowed when loading data to Oracle database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, etl

I am using sqlalchemy and pandas to load dataframe to Oracle database. Since 'multi'method allows to upload in bulk, I choose that method. My pandas version is 1.0.1. However I got the error as following:

> **The 'oracle' dialect with current database version settings does not support in-place multirow inserts.**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
oracle_connection_string = (
'oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@' +
cx_Oracle.makedsn('{hostname}', '{port}', service_name='{service_name}'))

engine = create_engine(oracle_connection_string.format(
    username='abc',
    password='123',
    hostname='bcd',
    port='1234',
    service_name='xyz.com',fast_executemany=True))
cleandata.to_sql('table', con = engine,schema = 'ht', if_exists='replace',index = False, method = 'multi')
```

So far I did not see any post having the same issue. Do you have any idea how to fix this?
P.s: When I eliminate the method multi, the code works. However for 10 records, it takes 2 mins to run. That is so costly. My table will have 4000 records. That's why I look for fast loading method on Python. Thanks!

Comment: What are the versions of the Oracle client libraries and Oracle DB?  FWIW, the cx_Oracle doc on batch loading is [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html), if you need to drop to raw cx_Oracle.

Comment: I did with batch loading as the attached doc. Indeed it reduce 95% time. I will stick to the recommendation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Chris mentioned, I used batch loading from [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

```
> cursor.executemany("insert into Table values (:1, :2)", dataToInsert')
```

That worked perfectly. From 120 seconds, I reduce 95%, to 5 second with the same number of uploaded records.

Comment: It is interesting that this was required, since pandas+sqla should default to using executemany as well underneath it all, I think.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I am also facing similar issue does it mean sqlalchemy can't support multi inserts for oracle due to some constraints in cx_oracle ?

Comment: Yes sql+pandas is supposed to run faster. I read many posts in different forums. So far they mentioned about fast_executemany in order to boost the upload process. It did not work for me though

Comment: The `fast_executemany` option is for pyodbc driver. @chidori Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Oracle or SQLA's dialect implementation to answer that.