# when using pandas.to_sql() with method = 'multi' for Oracle, got an error message 'CompileError' object has no attribute 'orig'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

when I insert my query result to an Oracle and even Netezza table, the code below works well with `queryResultToTable()` method, all records are loaded as expected.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas
import sys
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool # Import ThreadPool to enable parallel execution
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect        # Import create_engine to use Pandas database function, e.g. dataframe.to_sql()
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import \
            BFILE, BLOB, CHAR, CLOB, DATE, \
            DOUBLE_PRECISION, FLOAT, INTERVAL, LONG, NCLOB, \
            NUMBER, NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR2, RAW, TIMESTAMP, VARCHAR, \
            VARCHAR2
import netezza_dialect         

class databaseOperation():

    def queryResultToTable(self, sourceDBEngineURL, targetDBEngineURL, targetSchemaName, targetTableName, targetDataTypes, queryScript):
        sourceDBEngine = create_engine(sourceDBEngineURL)
        try:           
            with sourceDBEngine.connect() as sourceDBConnection:
                try:
                    queryResult = pandas.read_sql(queryScript,sourceDBConnection)    
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
        targetDBEngine = create_engine(targetDBEngineURL)
        try:
            with targetDBEngine.connect() as targetDBConnection:
                targetDBConnection.execution_options(autocommit = True)     # sumbit commit() automatically
                try:
                    queryResult.to_sql(targetTableName, targetDBConnection, targetSchemaName, if_exists = 'append', index = False, dtype = targetDataTypes, method = None)
                    # !!! method = 'multi' doesn't work for Oracle database
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return 
    
if __name__=='__main__':

    db = databaseOperation()

    sourceORAEngineURL = "....."  # the format like "oracle+cx_oracle://user:pwd@server_address1/db1"
    targetORAEngineURL = "....."  # the format like "oracle+cx_oracle://user:pwd@server_address2/db2"
    sql = "SELECT abc, def, ggg FROM table_name WHERE abc = 'txt'"
    ORA_targetSCHEMANAME = 'hr'
    ORA_targetTABLENAME = 'cmpresult'         
    ORA_tagetDATATYPES = {              
        'abc': NVARCHAR2(20),
        'def':  NVARCHAR2(100),
        'ggg':  NVARCHAR2(100)
    }

    db.queryResultToTable(sourceORAEngineURL, targetORAEngineURL, ORA_targetSCHEMANAME, ORA_targetTABLENAME, ORA_tagetDATATYPES, sql)      
   
    sys.exit(0)
```

But when I change method = None to method = 'multi', like:

```
queryResult.to_sql(targetTableName, targetDBConnection, targetSchemaName, if_exists = 'append', index = False, dtype = targetDataTypes, method = 'multi')
```

with the same method, Netezza works fine, but Oracle got the message as below:

```
'CompileError' object has no attribute 'orig'
```

other than that, no more information displayed, and I have no idea what issue is. I also tried to switch `Connection.execution_options(autocommit = True)` on or off, but no change.
could someone can help me out?

Comment: can you post a fuller code block and the full traceback please.

Comment: @born_naked, I edited my post already.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not supported for oracle db.
[Per pandas docs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ef9416c51c21365c15d8a07b8fc7e83435141fe2/doc/source/user_guide/io.rst#id231)

> Pass multiple values in a single INSERT clause. It uses a special SQL
> syntax not supported by all backends.

The SQL Alchemy documentation notes:

> Two phase transactions are not
> supported under cx_Oracle due to poor driver support. As of cx_Oracle
> 6.0b1, the interface for two phase transactions has been changed to be more of a direct pass-through to the underlying OCI layer with less
> automation. The additional logic to support this system is not
> implemented in SQLAlchemy.

This question suggests using [executemany from cx_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61749920/multi-method-is-not-allowed-when-loading-data-to-oracle-database-with-sqlalche)